# How to use Using statement for multiple instances?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to use `using` for `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects to dispose those. How can I use in this scenario?

for example:

```
using (sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(IRLConfigurationManager.GetConnectionString("connectionStringIRL")))
{
}
```

But here I am using connection based on the if condition.

```
SqlConnection _sqlConnection;
SqlCommand sqlCmd;
DBPersister per = (DBPersister)invoice;
if (per == null)
{
    _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(IRLConfigurationManager.GetConnectionString("connectionStringIRL"));
    sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("usp_UpdateDocumentStatusInImages", _sqlConnection);
}
else
{
    _sqlConnection = per.GetConnection();
    sqlCmd = per.GenerateCommand("usp_UpdateDocumentStatusInImages", _sqlConnection, per);
}

sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
//mycode

try
{
    if (_sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        _sqlConnection.Open();
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
finally
{
    if (per == null)
        invoice._sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: I guess you are restricted to the type for a single `using`

Answer (score 4):

You can nest them, like this:

```
using (var _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(...))
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you skip the {} and the indentation they even are more readable - I am all for {} but my coding standard has special notion for using statement chaining ;)

Comment: That seems strangely logical, and it looks like vs doesnt auto indent the second using. Why has no one told me this before?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [conditional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) operator to determine what to assign to each variable:

```
using(SqlConnection _sqlConnection = per==null?
      new SqlConnection(IRLConfigurationManager.GetConnectionString("connectionStringIRL"))
      : per.GetConnection())
using(SqlCommand sqlCmd = per==null?
      new SqlCommand("usp_UpdateDocumentStatusInImages", _sqlConnection);
      : per.GenerateCommand("usp_UpdateDocumentStatusInImages", 
       _sqlConnection, per))
{
  //Code here using command and connection
}
```

Although I must say, `per.GenerateCommand(..., per)` looks like an odd function (it's an instance method that also must be passed an instance of the same class - must it always be the same instance?)